# Kotlin create simple bitmap image file for JVM application (NOT Android)

Tags: kotlin

How can you create a bitmap image file with Kotlin for a basic JVM console app (not android)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` to create an image and `javax.imageio.ImageIO` to write to a file.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.awt.Dimension
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

fun main() {
    val size = Dimension(800, 600)
    val img = BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)        
    for (x in 0 until size.width){
        for (y in 0 until size.height) {
            img.setRGB(x, y, 0xff0000)
        }
    }    
    ImageIO.write(img, "BMP", File("test.bmp"))
}
```

Comment: (As a tiny tweak, `0 until size.first` might be slightly simpler than `0 .. size.first - 1`.  And if you want to use an object for the size instead of two separate variables, wouldn't a `Dimension` be clearer than a `Pair`?)

Comment: Thanks for that. Definitly a nice improvement. I have made those changes @gidds.